# How to handle defines from native code

Tags: java, dll

I have some native code that i want to call from java.
The functions return all a define for the state of the method.
What would be the best approach to get the string value associated in the .h file, since java  doesn't "know" defines. Im currently trying with enums, but i am not satisfied with that clunkyness. ( having several lists, trying to cast via the  cached .values list)

Comment: You should add some minimal sample code. Your question seems "unclear" to me.

Comment: @manuell of the header file? it is just an exported header file from a c++ dll with defines as return codes. The casting to enum works. I want to know if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't understand, then I don't know if there is "a better way". I think some minimal code sample should help.